# Laravel REST Full API как сделать авторизацию на VueJS?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, api, авторизация

Пишу REST Full API приложение на Laravel. Frontend частью выступает Vue JS
Хочу понять весь механизм авторизации.

Т.е. есть основной домен example.com (Frontend часть) и субдомен api.example.com (Backend API)

Comment: А что там понимать... К примеру, для сессий использовать отдельную таблицу sessions (user_id, token, created_at, expired_at) Регистрируется/Авторизируется пользователь - после проверки данных генерируете запись в sessions и отправляете ему в ответ нужные данные + токен (закодированный, напр. исп. sha1($toker)), на фронте берёте этот токен и сохраняете где-то (localstorage, session storage и т.п.) и при каждой загрузке страницы отправляете запрос, аля /check (отправляете токен и уже на беке берёте последний активный и смотрите истёк он или нет)

Comment: И при каждом запросе можно так же отправлять токен и, напр. в middleware смотреть истёк он или нет. Это только один из примеров как можно реализовать "доступ" в api. Ну, и для api лучше брать тот де Lumen, нет смысла "таскать" весь багаж laravel'а

Comment: @InDevX, простите за оффтоп, интересует такой момент. Если авторизация на Spring Security, то я правильно понимаю, что каждым запросом передаю в хедерах какой-то токен, который Spring сгенерировал для меня и хранит в оперативной памяти?

Comment: @Egettl увы, не знаком со spring security, поэтому не могу ответить на ваш вопрос. Но суть в том что на бекенде вы генерируете токен, который используете на фронте.

Comment: Можете также почитать про JWT token